# Secure browsing

Tags: security, chromium, extension

I would like to hear from you suggestions, how to improve security during browsing.

Let's say that I am going to use Chromium. With this extensions:

- Web of Thrust (to be noticed, if i visit bad website)
- AdBlock (block Ads, better performance)
- ScriptBlock (block malicious scripts)

Is this enough? I know, that if user is experienced, he doesn't need any of this extension. But i am going to use Ubuntu daily as my primary OS, so it is very big chance that i visit sometimes malicious website, and i am looking for the best extensions which notice me when i visit malicious website, and blocks its content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to be concerned about browser security?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95816/do-i-need-to-be-concerned-about-browser-security)

Comment: do **NOT install** the so called "Web of Trust" (**WOT**), it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any of them even if you are not experienced. The bigger problem is exploits (bugs that are used to gain access) in the browser. There have been a few (not that many), "flash" has had far more bugs that could be exploited.

- The 2nd one does nothing related to security.
- "scriptblock" I can see this help you be more secure.
- But "web of thrust" ... well ... nice idea but their method is seriously flawed: you will only be warned about a site they evaluated. That is too late since the harm has already been done before they evaluate a site.

  Plus you can be tricked: Let's assume I want to attack you personally due to you not upvoting my answer ( :) ). What about if I make a website I believe you will be interested in. I open a topic on their forums for people to evaluate it, I get a good evaluation, and then send you an invite to visit. I change a little bit of code to hack your system and then remove the code before anyone using WOT gets alarmed? I could keep that going for a long time while WOT claims my site is a wonderful piece of software.

  Nah, WOT makes you -feel- you are more secure but it is not actually making your surfing secure.

Now for some real pointers. What you need to avoid at any cost:

- never ever start a browser as "root" or with "sudo".
- use a good "sudo" password and never ever insert your password if asked and you do not understand why it is asked.
- backup your personal files. I myself do not store personal files in /home/ but use a different partition that is only mounted when I want it mounted. And it requires a password to mount for me as a -user- to mount it.

If anything happens then you loose your /home/ and nothing more.

If you do this the only problem you will have is a security bug inside the browser. If you are hit with this you are out of luck (as in: you should have bought a lottery ticket cuz you would have won the jackpot). If that ever happens you should remove your /home/ and recreate it with a restore of your backup.

Comment: Thank you for answer, so websites cannot inject chromium to download for example keylogger? And if website "attacks" on the browser, only home directory can be affected?

Comment: I'm interested to know under what circumstances could a web page running  browser gain access to your home directory - such that you would need to go to the trouble keeping personal files away from it?

Comment: 1. installing a keylogger from a browser would require your permission. You would need to download a file, execute it so to install it. And you need to run it too. Not likely to happen.  2.  For something to mess with your system outside of /home/ they need your user name and your "sudo" password. 1st is easy to get. 2nd is a lot more difficult (and if they do -you- probably gave it to them ;-) ). 2nd comment: I know none at the moment. http://heartbleed.com/ was a famous one regarding OpenSSL, VPN and IM and could be used to fish out text typed like passwords when typed.

Comment: So if website knowns your sudo password and your username is possible to make mess outside of home directory? So website can mess your home directory, without your sudo? Its Quite dangerous, so is better to keep your personal stuff outside /home and leave only config files in home?